# How to Loop on an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I run this code it reads only index 0 what is wrong?

**Javascript:**

```
function openTabs()
{
    var data = document.getElementById('excelData').value;
    var rows = data.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + rows[i]);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id = "excelData" name="excel_data" style="width:300px;height:580px;"></textarea><br>
<input type="button" onclick="openTabs()" value="Open Tabs"/>
```

Comment: you probably only have one "line" in the textarea

Comment: It's working fine with 5 lines of data.  https://jsfiddle.net/fgcw5hyn/

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: i'm using Chrome

Comment: I tried your code, and Chrome says that popups were blocked, I allowed them, and it worked fine then.

Comment: how Could i allow them?

Comment: In the address bar, click Pop-ups blocked and select "Always show pop-ups from [site]"

Comment: Thanks man, it works!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with neither the code before the loop nor the loop itself. I suspect the browser you are using is blocking you from opening som many windows.

You can verify this by changing the line to something else, for example `console.log(rows[i]);` and see if that outputs more than the first element in the index.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the browser. If you are using Chrome, it will block opening multiple windows at the same instant. To allow this, in the address bar, click Pop-ups blocked and select "Always show pop-ups from [site]"

Answer (score 0):

You can try by setting a the name property of the `window.open` method. ALong with that you may need to allow pop up from the browser.

Here is snippet to add name property to [**window.open**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

```
function openTabs() {
  var data = document.getElementById('excelData').value;
  var rows = data.split("\n");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    // second parameter is the name 
    window.open('http://www.google.com/search?q=' + rows[i],'newWindow'+i);
  }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k7xpegs8/)

**Allow popup from the browser option**

[image: Allow popup from the browser option]